# If i link page B from page A internally Does the page rank decrease?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

Does linking from one page(A) to another page(B) **[Internal link]** reduce the rank of the (A) page?
Assume that page A in search engine ranks 2nd, If I link to page B internally Does it affect the rank of page A?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does using links to other pages dilute the linking page's link juice/page rank?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129095/does-using-links-to-other-pages-dilute-the-linking-pages-link-juice-page-rank)

Comment: You appear to be confusing "PageRank" with "Ranking."   PageRank is a metric that Google uses internally to weight pages based on the number and quality of links to them.   Ranking is what position a page is in in the search results.   PageRank is one factor that Google uses for search engine rankings, but it is far from the only one.  Google used to make PageRank data public, but no longer does, so you can no longer get a number to assign to it.    It also doesn't make sense to say "2nd" for PageRank, that is more likely a search engine ranking that you are referring to.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no my mean is ranking, not "page rank" metric.

Comment: @Trebor no your question about an external link, but my question about the internal link

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Trebor question about an external link, but my question about the internal link, please open it again

Comment: So if external links don't dilute your page's rank, why would internal links dilute your rank?  The principle is the same.  If anything, well ranking pages with links to other internal pages, discourage users bouncing off of your site, which in the ancient past was a ranking factor (but no more).

Comment: @Trebor yes, it's true